# Are we praying or vowing to bring karbanos in musaf of shabas?

Tags: shabbat, tefilla, korban, nedarim-shevuot, musaf

In [*t'filas musaf*](http://www.sefaria.org/Siddur,_Sefard.20.1.23?lang=en&with=all&lang2=en) of *shabas* are we praying for Hashem to want us to bring the *karbanos*, or making an offer to bring them?

Two possible readings of this section are of the form "may it be your will, Hashem, that you bring us into the land happily and implant us in our borders...

*and [that] we do our obligatory karbanos there..."*

or

*and [then] we will do our obligatory karbanos there..."*

> יְהִי רָצוֹן מִלְּפָנֶיךָ ה' אֱ-לֹהֵינוּ וֵא-לֹהֵי אֲבוֹתֵינוּ. שֶׁתַּעֲלֵנוּ בְּשִׂמְחָה לְאַרְצֵנוּ וְתִטָּעֵנוּ בִּגְבוּלֵנוּ. *וְשָׁם נַעֲשֶׂה לְפָנֶיךָ אֶת קָרְבְּנוֹת חוֹבוֹתֵינוּ תְּמִידִים כְּסִדְרָם וּמוּסָפִים כְּהִלְכָתָם*.

That is, this could be a request that Hashem cause/enable us to bring the *karbanos* or a declaration that we will do so once we are brought to the land. The latter is plausible in that it is reminiscent of the type of contingent vow Ya'akov *avinu* took upon himself before travelling away from the land (*B'reshis* 28:20-22):

> וידר יעקב נדר לאמר אם יהיה א-להים עמדי ושמרני בדרך הזה אשר אנכי הולך ונתן לי לחם לאכל ובגד ללבש ושבתי בשלום אל־בית אבי והיה ה' לי לא-להים *והאבן הזאת אשר שמתי מצבה יהיה בית א-להים וכל אשר תתן לי עשר אעשרנו לך*
>
> :רש"י שם
>
> האבן הזאת כַּךְ תְּפָרֵשׁ וָי"ו זוּ שֶׁל וְהָאֶבֶן אִם תַּעֲשֶׂה לִי אֶת אֵלֶּה, אַנִי אֶעֱשֶׂה זׂאת

Some example translations:

The Koren Siddur, *nusach Ashkenaz* is consistent with this syntax, "...and plant us within our borders. *There we will prepare for You*...". The Artscroll English translation in the regular *nusach Ashkenaz* and *S'farad*, as well as the Expanded Edition *nusach Ashkenaz* all follow this pattern. The *Hirsch Siddur* follows the other pattern ("plant us so that we can bring...").

Although it has no period separating the phrases in the Hebrew, punctuation does not seem sufficient to indicate either way in most *sidurim* in situations such as these. As seen here, even the punctilious Koren version is not internally consistent when it comes to punctuation. I do not believe the conjugation of *na'ase* helps here either, as the jussive and plain future would be likely to sound identical.

Comment: Yaakov was agreeing to bring an extra offering. Korban Musaf is already an obligation.

Comment: Couldn't the phrase not be a request but a statement of fact?

Comment: @DoubleAA re Ya'akov, interesting point. It could be that that comparison is not deeper than a possible syntactic similarity. And yes, I would place any kind of declarative including acceptance and statement of fact in the same category here, as they are not part of the request.